# How to display marks in Percentage in SQL?

Tags: sql

As an example, I have this dataé

```
Total submission       170 
Passed Submission       32
Failed Submission      137
Skipped Submission       1
```

I need to be able to show:

1. Pass percentage
2. Fail Percentage
3. Skip percentage

Can someone help achieve this in SQL?

Comment: What have you tried? Please show an example of your work. StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Also know what database we are dealing with would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Its Worked For Me  - Answer is :**

convert(float,Secondset.PassedSubmission)*100/convert(float,FirstSet.TotalSubmission) as **PassPercentage**,

(convert(float,FirstSet.TotalSubmission)-(Convert(float,Secondset.PassedSubmission)+Convert(float,thirdset.SkippedSubmission)))*100/convert(float,FirstSet.TotalSubmission)) as **FailPercentage**,

convert(float,thirdset.SkippedSubmission)*100/convert(float,FirstSet.TotalSubmission) as **SkipPercentage**

Answer (score 0):

since I dont know what the table looks like here is an example on how it could look

```
select
      round(pass/total,2)*100 as passPercentage
    , round(fail/total,2)*100 as failPercentage
    , round(skip/total,2)*100 as skipPercentage
from table
```

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how your data is structured and how you want to return your results.  If you have a table with one row per submission and a `status` field, you can do either of these:

```sql
SELECT status, (COUNT(*) * 1.00) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM submission) AS status_pct
FROM submission
GROUP BY status
;

SELECT 
  (SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'passed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.00) / COUNT(*) AS pass_pct,
  (SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'failed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.00) / COUNT(*) AS fail_pct,
  (SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'skipped' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.00) / COUNT(*) AS skip_pct
FROM submission
;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f9f2a/8)